# Is the Websphere MQ Explorer SSL field "Accept only certificates with Distinguished Names matching these values field" case sensitive?

Tags: ssl, case, ibm-mq

I need to know if field `Accept only certificates with Distinguished Names matching these values field` under the `MQ channel SSL configuration` is case sensitive.

Comment: Can you please expand the question to explain where you are trying to configure this setting. What MQ software are you running? WebSphere MQ or something else? In its current state I don't think this question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute in the Windows Explorer GUI for WebSphere MQ maps to the SSLPEER value. The attribute types, for example CN, must be in uppercase characters.

Refer to the knowledge center which indicates the SSLPEER **Strings containing the same alphabetic characters match irrespective of case.**
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy12940_.htm